# Why is this While loop both doing and not doing what i told it too? (Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

So, before i begin, I'm going to say that I'm still learning Python, so while any answers are very appreciated, please don't give any advanced answers. So i just learned about while loops, and I'm coding in Reeborg's World. i am using the same code as my teacher, but when i run it, i create an infinite loop. here is a link to a pic of my code:

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxCKK.png)

and here is a link my my teacher's code:

[Teacher's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhIt1.png)

Any ideas why I creating an infinite loop, and my Teacher isn't?

Thanks much,
SmallCoder12

i tried adding multiple conditions to the while loop. i wanted it to go all the way to the flag, but instead it made Reeborg run into the wall.

Comment: When `front_is_clear` you erroneously `turn_left` because you have an incorrect indentation.

Comment: In the future, please post your code in text form with markdown rather than as images. [Why you should not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). For the markdown code, please note the "Code and preformatted text" section.

Comment: @Shorn I tried, but my teacher's code wasn't written down as a file, and when i used the code editor for my code (which i had pasted in), it still said i hadn't formatted it as code